# Retrieving data from hazelcast causes deserialize issue in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization, hazelcast

I am trying to store data in hazelcast the data get stored in hazelcast successfully the issue comes when I am trying to retrieve data from hazel cast it gives deserialize exception I debugged the program and saw there is a source paramter added to my hazel output
I have mentioned the code below
**Student.class**

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Student {
    String studentId;
    String studentDetails;
}
```

HazelCast class entity
HazelCast.class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentCache implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String studentId;
    String studentDetails;
}

public class StudentCacheServiceImpl implements StudentCacheService {

    @Autowired
    HazelcastInstance instance;

    IMap<String, StudentCache> studentMap;

    String students = "STUDENT_MAP";


    @Override
    public StudentCache findById(String studentId) {
        StudentCache studentCache = studentMap.get(studentId);
        return studentCache;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(StudentCache studenteCache) {
            studentMap.put(studentCache.getStudentId, studentCache, 50, TIMEUNIT.MINUTES);
         
        } 
    }
}
```

Whenever I am trying to use finder method I face the issue of deserialization I am able to successfully put data into hazelcast but I am not able to map data to a Dto when I use hazelcast finder method

The issue is with this part

```
 @Data
        @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
        public class StudentHazel {
            String studentId;
            String studentDetails;
        }

StudentCache studentCache=StudentCacheServiceImpl.findById(studentId);
                StudentHazel studentHazel = objectMapper.readValue(studentCache.getStudentDetails(), StudentHazel.class);
```

The objectMapper part fails to map data to my StudentHazel dto how can I resolve this issue

Comment: What's the  stacktrace ? What the output if you add `System.out.println(studentCache)` immediate prior to your `objectMappper.readValue(..` line. Is the `studentDetails` JSON ?

Comment: I am getting this error Cannot construct instance of `com.demo.StudentCache` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{')

Comment: What does `System.out.println(studentCache)` show ? The full detail will confirm if the issue is with Hazelcast or the object mapper